# Selenium webdriver unable to create a Firefox instance

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def set_pref(path):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                           "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.msexcel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream")
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                           "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.msexcel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream")
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


def main():
    display = Display(visible=1, size=(1050, 800))
    display.start()
    driver = set_pref(path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my code. I am trying to create a Firefox instance using webdriver.
I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 226, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_script.py", line 207, in main
    driver = set_pref(path)
  File "my_script.py", line 44, in set_pref
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  File "/home/krupa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/krupa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/krupa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/krupa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/krupa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

firefox version 63.0 | 
selenium version 3.14.1 | 
geckodriver version 0.18.0

I am not able to run any of my scripts since morning. Not able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Perhaps your geckodriver needs to be updated? https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases (Found this link on the [selenium page](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).)

Comment: 1. Try [updating your geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).      2. Double check if Firefox executable is in your PATH.

Comment: @AshishKamble You are actively contributing to the community for quite some time now and some of your answers were phenomenal. Having said that asking a new contributor to downgrade geckodriver version to 0.19.0 against the current version of 0.23.0 is not only unethical but also against all the best practices. Please take care of your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

According to this compatibility chart https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html your geckodriver does not support Firefox >62. So the answer might be simple: update your geckodriver.

Comment: Yes the versions of Firefox and geckodriver were incompatible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To always verify geckodriver is compatible with your current firefox & selenium version, do the following:

Keep downloaded geckodriver at System32 if you are on Windows OS & /usr/local/bin if you are on Mac OSX. Download from [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

1. Run the Selenium Standalone server by this command:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar

2. Open this url in Firefox browser:

> http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

3. Create Session and Select Firefox browser
   If browser starts then there is no issue with the compatibility of geckodriver with Firefox & Selenium version.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. It seems useful.